# How can i make disable Notification in preference in android

Tags: java, android

How can i make disable Notification in preference in android?(if the user do not like the see the notification but the notification still in the app) i already doing check Box in xml

```
      <CheckBoxPreference 
      android:title="Disable Notification"
      android:defaultValue="true"
      android:key="checkbox"
      android:summary="Check the Box"/>
```

but i do not know what is the code to disable Notification, Thank you in advance !

Comment: I don't think you can disable all the notifications. You can probably disable your own application's notifications. You can also set your app to fullscreen mode, and hide the notification bar.

Comment: yeah that is what i mean, sorry if i did not mention that, i mean my own Notification

Comment: If we are talking about your own notification, then you can just avoid creating them when they are disabled in your configuration.

Comment: NO I just update my question. i want the notification but when the user do not like the push notification and want to disable it in Screen

Answer (score 0):

```
notificationManager.cancelAll()
```

.... that's the notification manager object

Comment: you mean i should just put this little code? also i do not want it to canceled, just disabled

Comment: yeah... it will cancel sounds, vibrations, the persistent status bar icon (if any).... What exactly do you mean by disable ? you mean stop the notification right?

Comment: then write this in onDestroy() of your activity.

Comment: @KKD i try this put it gives me Synatx error. This is my code: `protected void onDestroy() {
  NotificationManager.cancelAll();}`

Comment: i wanna disable Notification SMS, MMS, Alarm.

Comment: @KKD i am using dialog Notification so when i put this statement `protected void onDestroy() {  NotificationManager.cancelAll();}` it give me syntax error. so i declare varible.then run it, but the dialog notification (alarm , ..) still appear, should i use something specail to dialog?

Comment: @Maha: I don't understand you are using dialog (like processDialog) or NotificationManager?..... If you are using the Notification Manager make sure you are not directly calling it on android.app.NotificationManager.... you are supposed to create an object and then call cancelAll().... like this NotificationManager notifyObject; notifyObject = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); notifyObject.cancelAll(); //you can only cancel the notification Manager's notification by cancel all function. Not processDialog or anything. It will be better if you paste some code or ERRORs